# Should a superclass of a number of subclasses be more general or more specific?

Tags: python

I noticed that often times, I do not clearly know whether a superclass of a number of subclasses should be more general or more restricted regarding the attributes. Here is a contrived example to illustrate what I mean:

```
# A) superclass more general (union of attributes)
class human:
    self.__init__(height, beardColor, nailColor):
        self.height=height
        self.beardColor=beardColor
        self.nailColor=nailColor

class man(human):
    self.__init__(heigth, beardColor):
        super().__init__(height, beardColor, None)

class woman(human):
    self.__init__(heigth, nailColor):
        super().__init__(height, None, nailcolor)

# B) superclass more specific (intersection of attributes)
class human:
    self.__init__(height):
        self.height=height

class man(human):
    self.__init__(heigth, beardColor):
        super().__init__(height)
        self.beardColor=beardColor

class woman(human):
    self.__init__(heigth, nailColor):
        super().__init__(height)
        self.nailColor=nailColor
```

It somehow boils down to the question whether a superclass should possess the union of all attributes of subclasses or rather their intersection.

Are their any general rules for which paradigm is better?

Comment: I suppose it depends if you want bearded ladies or not

Comment: I would say you have specific and general backwards in your example. The more general one has *fewer* attributes. You should be using B.

Comment: @Sayse Or men with crazy nail colors :)

Comment: It depends on how your super classes are designed to be used. If you want to be able to access the beard and nail color of *each* human, use A. A comes with the possibilities of creating bearded women and men with colorful nails as stated by @DeepSpace and @Sayse. If you won't be doing something like `for human in earth: print(human.beardColor)`, use B.

Comment: I actually don't understand why people vote for closing, rather than sharing their arcane wisdom.